# Calling a method with (sometimes) null parameters to execute an SQL statement. C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a method and am trying to figure out how to handle calling that method with null parameters.

```
public static List<Incident> GetIncidentByTechnician(int techID)
    {
        List<Incident> incidents = new List<Incident>();

            Incident inc = null; // found incident
                                 // define connection
            SqlConnection connection = TechSupportDB.GetConnection();

            // define the select query command
            string selectQuery = "select IncidentID, CustomerID, ProductCode, TechID, DateOpened, DateClosed, Title, Description " +
                                 "from Incidents " +
                                 "where TechID = @TechID";

        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechID", techID);
            try
            {   
                // open the connection
                connection.Open();

                // execute the query
                SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                // process the result while there are incidents
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    inc = new Incident();
                    inc.IncidentID = (int)reader["IncidentID"];
                    inc.CustomerID = (int)reader["CustomerId"];
                    inc.ProductCode = reader["ProductCode"].ToString();
                    inc.TechID = (int)reader["TechID"];
                    inc.DateOpened = (DateTime)reader["DateOpened"];
                    inc.DateClosed = (DateTime?)reader["DateClosed"];
                    inc.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
                    inc.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();
                    incidents.Add(inc); //add to the list
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; // let the form handle it
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close(); // close connecto no matter what
            }
        return incidents;
    }
```

it takes "techID" integer as parameter and populates a list of incidents with that technician ID. However, some incidents have null values for techID. I don't want them to be added into my list.

I tried an if(techID !=null) but that gives an error saying it will always be true. I think my sql statement is not good since "where TechID = null " doesn't return results and it should be "where TechID is null" when testing this statement in sql server management studio. Any suggestions to handle these null values?
Also my incident class is shown below. I set the techID to accept null values with int?.

```
    public class Incident
{
    public Incident() { }
    public int IncidentID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int? TechID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOpened { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateClosed { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, when you are doing TechID = @TechID on query, how come there is null TechID on list?

Answer (score 0):

You should add another condition `TechID IS NOT NULL` to check for non nulity in your `SELECT` query like

```
SELECT IncidentID, CustomerID, ProductCode, TechID, DateOpened, DateClosed, 
Title, Description from Incidents 
where TechID = @TechID AND TechID IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader["Tech"] != null)
    {
        inc = new Incident();
        inc.IncidentID = (int)reader["IncidentID"];
        inc.CustomerID = (int)reader["CustomerId"];
        inc.ProductCode = reader["ProductCode"].ToString();
        inc.TechID = (int)reader["TechID"];
        inc.DateOpened = (DateTime)reader["DateOpened"];
        inc.DateClosed = (DateTime?)reader["DateClosed"];
        inc.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
        inc.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();
        incidents.Add(inc); //add to the list
    }
}
```

Just don't create or add the `Incident` object if you have a null value...

Answer (score 0):

According to your function prototype, `techID` is an integer and is not nullable:

```
public static List<Incident> GetIncidentByTechnician(int techID)
```

This means that the SQL call will never include a null `@techID`, because it is assigned from the non-nullable `techID`:

```
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TechID", techID);
```

So your select statement should only return rows with a non-null techID. It has to match, after all.

```
select IncidentID, CustomerID, ProductCode, TechID, DateOpened, DateClosed, Title, Description 
from Incidents
where TechID = @TechID
```

Therefore the reader should never return a null `techID` either:

```
inc.TechID = (int)reader["TechID"];
```

Given the code sample you have provided, null `TechID` values should not be an issue. You should not have to add an `if` or amend your `where` clause to handle null `techID` values, because they will not be allowed by the c# code.

You have tried running the code as is?